# The Hopf Fibration and Frobenius' Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

Consider the Hopf fiber of the $\mathbb{S}^3$ sphere over the $\mathbb{S}^2$ sphere. Consider the two-dimensional distribution in $\mathbb{S}^3$ that is orthogonal to the fibers of this fiber. Use Frobenius' theorem to show that this distribution is not completely integrable.

This problem is taking away my peace, I cannot develop anything plausible.

What I thought is that we have to determine a $1-$form $\omega$ in an open $\mathbb{S}^3$ (I think) that represents the differential system defined by the orthogonal distribution of the fibers, the idea would be to find a diffeomorphism $\varphi$  of a coordinate system in $\mathbb{S}^3$ defined by the canonical system. My interest is to show that $\mathrm{d} \omega \wedge \omega =0$, for this I use the fact that $\varphi$ is diffeomorphism, then it is equivalent to show that $\varphi^*(\mathrm{d} \omega \wedge \omega) =0$ (I think it gets easier). Then, doing some calculations we arrived at the conditions of integrability

Comment: First, which definition of the Hopf fibration do you want to use?

Comment: @Deane the same definition as Wikipedia [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_fibration)

Comment: There's more than one in the article. Which one is easiest for you to understand?

Comment: @Deane by direct construction.

Comment: @Deane I know in theory, but doing the math is not coming out, it is one of the most difficult theories I have seen in mathematics.

Comment: I'm confused. The point is to show that $d\omega\wedge\omega\ne 0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin, The point is to show that $\mathrm{d}\omega \wedge \omega = 0$, we would arrive in conditions of integrability. I think the point is this, show $\mathrm{d}\omega \wedge \omega \neq 0$

Comment: You’re wrong. You need to show the distribution is *not* integrable. Indeed, this result is well-known because the Euler class of the Hopf circle bundle is nonzero.

Comment: @TedShifrin I corrected my comment. You're right.

Comment: Yup. :) So what's the $1$-form?

Comment: @TedShifrin This I still don't know, how the 1-form would look

Comment: What's the vector field tangent to the Hopf fibers? Start there and work.

Comment: I am feeling incapacitated, what a difficult question.